# groovy vs fuerte

Tags: ros-fuerte, ros-groovy, rosserial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello

I just want to know , the differences and the new or better things on ROS groovy, or why this could be better than ROS fuerte. I'm working with fuerte and since few days ago i'm having many problems installing some things like rosserial. So i don't know if it's cause is other version of ROS now.

thnks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/53294/groovy-vs-fuerte/) by [monidiaz](https://answers.ros.org/users/3475/monidiaz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 92 on 2013-01-24

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should have a look at the [groovy wiki page](http://www.ros.org/wiki/groovy). It has what the major updates are and what you need to do to migrate.

---

Originally posted by [thebyohazard](https://answers.ros.org/users/1483/thebyohazard/) with karma: 3562 on 2013-01-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In general groovy has not been out for that long, so you should run into less problems and find more help with fuerte than with groovy.

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2013-01-24

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [monidiaz](https://answers.ros.org/users/3475/monidiaz/) on 2013-01-24**:
thnks, so i must been here using fuerte for now.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can also look up specific components, like the **rosserial** [Release page](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosserial/Releases) and [Change List](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosserial/ChangeList).

Oddly, it appears that the most recent rosserial-0.3.0 release is only available for Electric. Fuerte and Groovy are still at version 0.2.0. You might want to contact the **rosserial** developers about that.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2013-01-24

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2